# $\tau:=\{Y\in P(X) | A\subseteq Y\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ topological space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $A\subseteq X$

I would like to show that $\tau:=\{Y\in P(X) | A\subseteq Y\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$is a topological space on $X$ and afterwards I would like to describe the closure $\bar{E}$ and the inner $E°$ concerning $\tau$ for arbitrary subsets $E\subseteq X$

Well first of all $\emptyset \in\tau, X\in\tau$ is clear.Any union of open sets is open: This is intuitviely clear but I do not know how to show that, the same with The intersection of any finite number of open sets is open.

May you could help me with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any open set is either empty or it contains the set $A$. The union, and intersection, of any collection of sets that contain $A$, will also contain $A$.

Formally, let me write the union parts, and you can do the intersection:

> Let $\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$ be a collection of open sets, and let $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$. We want to show that $U$ is open, that is either $U=\varnothing$ or $A\subseteq U$. If for some $i$, $U_i\neq\varnothing$ then $A\subseteq U_i$, and therefore $A\subseteq U_i\subseteq U$, so $A\subseteq U$ and so $U$ is open; otherwise $U_i=\varnothing$ for all $i\in I$ and so $U=\varnothing$ as well.

For the intersection part you *may* want to chase down the elements from $A$; also remember it is enough to show that the intersection of *two* open sets is open in order to conclude the general finite case.

Comment: Thanks, here my way for the intersection: $Let U_1,U_2\in\tau$ open sets, I want to show that $U_1\cap U_2$ is open, i.e $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$ or $A\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$. 1.case: $U_1=U_2=\emptyset$ => $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$. 2.case: $A\subseteq U_1$ and $A\subseteq U_2$, therefore $A\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$. Do you have any suggestion for the description of $\bar{E}$ and $E^°$ ?

Comment: @Babla: Do note that in the first case only one of the sets have to be empty. Now note that if $E$ is open then it's either empty or dense; and if $E$ is not open then its interior must be empty (why?). Closure is slightly trickier, but note that a set is closed if and only if it is disjoint from $A$, or the entire space. Conclude that closures are either $E$ or $X$ itself.

Comment: Ok, to write it a little bit more formally: Suppose $E$ open, therefore $E=\emptyset$ or  $\bar{E}=X$. Suppose $E$ is not open => $E^°=\emptyset$ (I still do not see it). If E is closed => $E\cap A=\emptyset$ or $E=X$, therefore $E=\bar{E}$ or $E=X$

Comment: @Babla: If $E$ is not open, then $A\nsubseteq E$. What sort of open subsets $E$ has? Recall that $E^\circ\subseteq E$. Also remember that there are sets which are neither open nor closed.

Comment: If E is not open, the only open subsets are $E^°$ and $\emptyset$ right?, but $\emptyset$ is open and closed.

Comment: @Babla, $E^\circ$ is the maximal open subset of $E$, we define it *from* the open subsets of $E$. If $A\nsubseteq E$, what could possibly be the open subsets of $E$ that would make $E^\circ$?

Comment: If $E^°=\bigcup_{G\subseteq E, G open} G$ and $A\notsubseteq E$ the only possible open subset can be $\emptyset$

Comment: Correct. Therefore the interior of non-open sets would be?

Comment: Why non-open sets? We just analyzed the case where $E$ is not open?

Comment: Yes, but you said that you didn't see why the interior of non open sets is empty. I was trying to help you tie up the loose ends. Anyhow, as for the closure I hope you can manage on your own, as I have to go for a few hours. Follow my hints, and the approach we took with the interiors, and you should be fine!